# What does a 'resume' for a US company in Europe include?

Tags: resume

I am wanting to apply for a job at a US company based in Europe (Switzerland). On their application site they ask for a resume. 
I am used to uploading one document with CV, certificates, references as a single PDF. 
The 'resume' they ask for is quite limited in size.

Do I only upload my resume/CV or should I include certificates, etc. as well?

Thank you for any hints :-)

Comment: 'Resume' and 'CV' are interchangeable terms. Can you clarify what you mean by _The 'resume' they ask for is quite limited in size?_

Comment: @MikeHarris  They are not exactly interchangeable.  US resumes are quite a bit shorter and less detailed than a CV.

Answer (score 4):

You asked,

> Do I only upload my resume/CV or should I include certificates, etc. as well?

If they ask only for a resume, you should upload only your resume. In the US, "resume" is essentially equivalent to the CV you're used to in Europe, and it does *not* explicitly include certificates, diplomas, portfolios, letters of reference, cover letters, or other materials. Employers who want those additional materials usually either ask for them separately or otherwise indicate how to submit them.

When in doubt though, it may make sense to reach out to a recruiter at the employer you're interested in and ask.

Comment: A minor clarification, while actual copies of the certificates aren't expected, a list of any relevant certifications is normal in the US.

Answer (score 0):

Resume is different from CV in a sense that it should not include any information that can be used to discriminate against a candidate - information that American employers are forbidden to ask for by law - and that European CVs often include.

In short it should not contain any information about your age, gender, race, nationality and so on.

Resume is focused primarily on your work experience and relevant skills as they were applied in your previous employment. If you are a young person with little experience you can include more extensive information on your education.

Otherwise, if you have more than 10 years of experience, American employers don't care about your education beyond knowing your education level: "Master of Engineering, Mechanical Engineering, Virginia Polytechnic Institute" is enough. If they care about specific education requirements, it will be included in the job description.

There are many Resume examples online to look at. You might get extra points for making an effort to send an actual Resume rather than CV... :-)

Answer (score 0):

When hiring in the US, I've seen many resumes and a few CVs. A resume is organized by sections, such as Contact, Goal, Skills, Experience, Education, Patents and Publications, and so forth. Its point is to be read quickly for the high points. Think of it as a sales brochure for you. It says what you know, what you've done, and why those things will be important when you get the job.

A *curriculum vitae* (CV) is generally a chronological list of events and achievements in your life. It gets longer as you do more.

I guess an American firm in Switzerland often receives CVs and knows how to read them. Still, you may want to write a resume for them. In your cover letter you can mention "CV, certificates, and references upon request."

There are many examples of both on the intertoobz.